# N-ary Generic Tree -- Java Interview

Tags: java, generics, tree

Please forgive me if this question has already been asked. I recently had an interview for a job after completing a code assessment that was based on the use of an n-ary tree & two traversal methods.

As most of the examples on this site, I used Generics to define my Tree/Node data types so as to enforce the strict use of whatever data type that I declare the Tree type with. Well, to make a long story short, my results were fine but the interviewer asked me why I chose to use Generics for my Tree data structure. I told him because it was the best way to enforce the data type of whatever type of tree I wanted to use in my assessment. I also told him that I'd done a similar data structure before, and remembered how to implement it.

Is my answer to his first question far off ?

Answer (score 0):

[Why Use Generics?](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/why.html):

Code that uses generics has many benefits over non-generic code:

- Stronger type checks at compile time.
  A Java compiler applies strong type checking to generic code and issues errors if the code violates type safety. Fixing compile-time errors is easier than fixing runtime errors, which can be difficult to find.
- Elimination of casts.

The following code snippet without generics requires casting:

```
List list = new ArrayList();
list.add("hello");
String s = (String) list.get(0);
```

When re-written to use generics, the code does not require casting:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("hello");
String s = list.get(0);   // no cast
```

- Enabling programmers to implement generic algorithms.
  By using generics, programmers can implement generic algorithms that work on collections of different types, can be customized, and are type safe and easier to read.

Now, you can compare your answer with one of the best answers (if not the best).

Comment: Gotcha, I appreciate the quick feedback! This helped.